# unable to set a toogle button effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am in a bit Dilemma here.
what I am trying to do is I am trying to make 2 side by side buttons and when one is hovered it changes the background Color and when the other is hovered it changes . like a  toggle.
Now the problem comes that i want when one is clicked it retains the effect like adding a class but now what happens is that when I  mouseleave it does not retain it's state.
please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
here

Here is the Fiddle[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kuqt2/)

Some code is like this

```
  $('#masterContainer #leftDiv').mouseenter(function (event) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
            $(this).css('color', 'white');
            $('#masterContainer #leftDiv img').attr('src', 'heartWhite.png');
        });
```

Comment: When i hover on second button it should chanage the bg colour of second    image. it works fine but when i click that button, it should stay with that bg., Now the point is i added a clicked class, but when i hover out it again uses that mouseout event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's waaaay too much javascript going there for such a simple thing. (If I'm understanding what you are seeking.)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xYLyT/2/

Let CSS do the work. :)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box zuck">
        Zuck
    </div>
    <div class="box albert">
        Albert
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.box').click(function (event) {
    $('.box').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color : silver;
  margin           : 0;
  padding          : 0;
}
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.container {
  border : 2px solid black;
  float  : left;
  height : 180px;
  width  : 803px;
}

.box {
  border-right : 1px solid black;
  float        : left;
  height       : 100%;
  transition   : all 1s ease 0s;
  width        : 50%;
  padding: 0;
}
.box:hover,
.box.clicked {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.zuck {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUZnc_P0eH1w67I_YaaWo18Tgt83RFrepGDJm-AA8d9pg_kWM8Pw') no-repeat center center;

}

.albert {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYtxk2DUEWNsNpH0jTMqLc22tYccLZiwYxiCKKOCLGTVr2QZp_nw') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation(); please tell me what does this mean?

Comment: It prevents the event from bubbling. http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1):

If you delegate all of your styles to CSS classes then you can simplify your problem so that all you have to do is change the class of the box on `hover` and on `click`.

For example, assuming markup:

```
<div class="box">container one</div>

<div class="box">container two</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: #cdcdcd;
}
.box.hovered, .box.clicked {
    background: #797979;
}
```

You can achieve the effect it sounds like you're after with:

```
// Handle the mouseenter/leave events with a unique class
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
// Handle click event with a different class and toggle method
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Alternatively, if you'd like the boxes to *switch* based on click, you can use:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).siblings('.box').addClass('hovered')
});
// Use this block instead of the previous `click` handler above
```

The advantage to abstracting your styles over to your stylesheet (rather than using the `.css` method) is that:

A. It separates your appearance out from markup (seperation of concerns), and avoids override issues with inline-styles.

B. It dramatically simplifies your DOM interactions by reducing the problem to class addition/removal.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUqeC/4/)

Comment: Hey when i click the button 1 the button effect should be removed and should strick to button 1. thanks

Comment: JUST ONCE QUESTION, what does this mean  event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Is this not the behavior you were looking to accomplish??